# Objective-C Astronomy Library

Tags: objective-c, astronomy

I need to do some moonrise azimuth and time calculations.  Can anyone recommend a good astronomy library, preferably in Objective-C?

Answer (score 12):

I recommend PJ Naughter's [AA+ library](http://www.naughter.com/aa.html).  It is based on the Astronomical Algorithms book by Meeus.  The library is quite comprehensive and written in C++ (easily called from Objective-C).  My iOS app [Lúan](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id305665185?mt=8) uses this library.

Comment: I downloaded AA+ library, but would you please let me know how to add C++ files to XCode iOS project? I tried but it errors at **class** keyword!

Comment: When integrating AA+, remove the tests as they contain a main function that will conflict with your projects main.  rename obj-c files that need to reference C++ code to end in .mm instead of .m.  Doing so will put the compiler in objective-c++ mode for that file.

Comment: You can't find the sun and moon rise and set is that right?

Comment: You can use the library for sun/moon rise/set.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe code of opensource projects could fit you? Recently on [FLOSS-Weekly](http://twit.tv/FLOSS) was a discussion about [Stellarium](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stellarium/develop).

Disclaimer: I didn't look at that source of Stellarium so I have no idea if it is useful at all and unfortunately it is written in C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

Its not in objective C but the library included in the pyephem package is quite good. The C source files were taken from the old X windows xephem program with glue added to make the functions available from within Python. As long as you don't require super-high accuracy, these routines will probably work for you.

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/

Answer (score 2):

For those still interested in 2016, I've made an Objective-C(++) and Swift wrapper around PJ Naughter's AA+ library. It is based on the Astronomical Algorithms book by Jean Meeus and it is open-source on GitHub:

https://github.com/onekiloparsec/SwiftAA

Answer (score 1):

There's an old C library called Astrolog that can probably do some of the stuff you're asking.  You can check it out here: http://www.astrolog.org/astrolog.htm

Answer (score 1):

On top of Andrew Hammond answer, I just use Xcode to download the AA.  I then remove all the Test files (AATest.cpp AATest.sin AATest.vcproj) and with a warning by Xcode of "Implicit conversion loss integer precision 'long' to 'int'" in the last line on nYear / 100

```
CAAEasterDetails CAAEaster::Calculate(long nYear, bool GregorianCalendar)
{
  CAAEasterDetails details;

  if (GregorianCalendar)
  {                      
    int a = nYear % 19;
    int b = nYear / 100;
```

The program compile ok.  Only compile if the program is objective c but not if it is Swift based.  Got a problem with pre-processor macro  AAPLUS_EXT_CLASS.