# Accurately calculate moon phases

Tags: objective-c, astronomy

For a new project I like to calculate the moon phases. So far I haven't seen any code that does that. I don't want to rely on online-services for this.

I have tried some functions, but they are not 100% reliable. Functions I have tried:

```
NSInteger r = iYear % 100;

    r %= 19;
    if (r>9){ r -= 19;}
    r = ((r * 11) % 30) + iMonth + iDay;
    if (iMonth<3){r += 2;}
    r -= ((iYear<2000) ? 4 : 8.3);
    r = floor(r+0.5);
```

other one:

```
float n = floor(12.37 * (iYear -1900 + ((1.0 * iMonth - 0.5)/12.0)));
    float RAD = 3.14159265/180.0;
    float t = n / 1236.85;
    float t2 = t * t;
    float as = 359.2242 + 29.105356 * n;
    float am = 306.0253 + 385.816918 * n + 0.010730 * t2;
    float xtra = 0.75933 + 1.53058868 * n + ((1.178e-4) - (1.55e-7) * t) * t2;
    xtra = xtra + (0.1734 - 3.93e-4 * t) * sin(RAD * as) - 0.4068 * sin(RAD * am);
    float i = (xtra > 0.0 ? floor(xtra) :  ceil(xtra - 1.0));
    float j1 = [self julday:iYear iMonth:iMonth iDay:iDay];
    float jd = (2415020 + 28 * n) + i;
    jd = fmodf((j1-jd + 30), 30);
```

and last one

```
        NSInteger thisJD = [self julday:iYear iMonth:iMonth iDay:iDay];
    float degToRad = 3.14159265 / 180;
    float K0, T, T2, T3, J0, F0, M0, M1, B1, oldJ = 0.0;
    K0 = floor((iYear-1900)*12.3685);
    T = (iYear-1899.5) / 100;
    T2 = T*T; T3 = T*T*T;
    J0 = 2415020 + 29*K0;
    F0 = 0.0001178*T2 - 0.000000155*T3 + (0.75933 + 0.53058868*K0) - (0.000837*T + 0.000335*T2);
    M0 = 360*[self getFrac:((K0*0.08084821133)) + 359.2242 - 0.0000333*T2 - 0.00000347*T3];
    M1 = 360*[self getFrac:((K0*0.07171366128)) + 306.0253 + 0.0107306*T2 + 0.00001236*T3];
    B1 = 360*[self getFrac:((K0*0.08519585128)) + 21.2964 - (0.0016528*T2) - (0.00000239*T3)];
    NSInteger phase = 0;
    NSInteger jday = 0;
    while (jday < thisJD) {
        float F = F0 + 1.530588*phase;
        float M5 = (M0 + phase*29.10535608)*degToRad;
        float M6 = (M1 + phase*385.81691806)*degToRad;
        float B6 = (B1 + phase*390.67050646)*degToRad;
        F -= 0.4068*sin(M6) + (0.1734 - 0.000393*T)*sin(M5);
        F += 0.0161*sin(2*M6) + 0.0104*sin(2*B6);
        F -= 0.0074*sin(M5 - M6) - 0.0051*sin(M5 + M6);
        F += 0.0021*sin(2*M5) + 0.0010*sin(2*B6-M6);
        F += 0.5 / 1440; 
        oldJ=jday;
        jday = J0 + 28*phase + floor(F);
        phase++;
    }
    float jd = fmodf((thisJD-oldJ), 30);
```

All are working more and less, but none is really giving the correct dates of full moon for 2017 and 2018.

Does anyone have a function that will calculate the moon phases correctly - also based on time zone?

EDIT:
I only want the function for the Moonphases. SwiftAA offers a lot more and only produces not needed overhead in the app.

Comment: Oops sorry for the mis-tag. That was sort of an automatism, ha

Comment: Try to use approrpiate library, say libNOVA. It even have an example for lunar calculations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C Astronomy Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348415/objective-c-astronomy-library)

Comment: For NASA-grade accuracy, you need the CSPICE libraries: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/index.html

Comment: Hi. SwiftAA author here. Anything I can do to soften these "overheads" you're talking about?

Comment: "none is really giving the correct dates of full moon for 2017 and 2018". What makes you think the ones you got are "the correct" ones? Maybe they've been calculated using a different, and even worse, algorithm?